# Way to make date field to show only past date(less than current date)

Tags: javascript, archer, rsa-archer-grc

Could you please share a sample custom object code to restrict the user from selecting the future date and populate a warning message from the questionnaire?
Using version -6.9 SP2

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you really want but what I am guessing is that you want to ensure that user only pick dates earlier than the current date in date input element.
For this you can use the "min" value of the date input field and set it to current date.